# Opening Quadratic Sieve Jar file in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, jar

I hope the title isn't misleading.. It was hard to come up with a proper name for this. Anyways, I'm trying to implement the Quadratic Sieve method for factoring integers in Java for problem solving purposes, as it will make my life a bit easier. I've tried to write the program myself, but it has a few flaws, rendering it unusable as of this moment.

So what I tried was to find a Java implementation of this Quadratic sieve method to locate my mistakes and correct if needed, or even use it.

I entered wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve at which the last implementation of **Ariel**, under the "implementations" section, is a Java implementation of this Quadratic Sieve method. I downloaded it and, unsurprisingly, it is a **Jar** file.. And opening it with "Java (TM) Platform SE Binary" doesn't work. Opening it with WinRAR later gives a list of a few folders that each contains lots of Classes within it.

Now, what I want is to somehow open all the classes and code written in that file, in my Eclipse IDE. Or a simpler explanation to this, is that I simply want to run this program in Eclipse, and view the code.

Question is, how do i do that :S?

Please be nice, I might be a good programmer, but I'm not as good in computers in general, try not to mock me :D

Thanks in advance, Matan.

Comment: `jar` you downloaded contains compiled `.class` files. You should look for sources (`.java` files). However you can decompile `.class` but it's not a very good option if you want to read the sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the source files.  They're not in the .jar, but you can get them here:

http://sourceforge.net/p/arielqs/code/HEAD/tree/src/

Click on "download snapshot" to get a .zip of all the sources

Comment: Ok what do I do after i have the zip/winRAR folder with the sources? i mean what do i do with it? how do i insert it to my project and use it?

Comment: Create a new java project in Eclipse, open the source folder in explorer, drag the files from winrar into the source folder, and refresh the source folder in Eclipse.

Comment: Eventually I managed to get it into the project and run it, but it's false.. doesn't produce prime factorization, but rather a factorization into 2 of its divisors, e.g 300 ----> 5,60. Refer here please if u maybe can help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581520/quadratic-sieve-java-implementation

Comment: If any of the factors aren't prime, you can just call it again on those factors.  I'm not familiar with the code base, but there's probably a primality test in there somewhere -- it's much easier than factoring.